# Plot causes "Error: Incorrect Number of Dimensions"

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-visualization, cluster-analysis, data-manipulation

I am learning about the "kohonen" package in R for the purpose of making Self Organizing Maps (SOM, also called Kohonen Networks - a type of Machine Learning algorithm). I am following this R language tutorial over here: https://www.rpubs.com/loveb/som

I tried to create my own data (this time with both "factor" and "numeric" variables) and run the SOM algorithm (this time using the "supersom()" function instead):

```
#load libraries and adjust colors

library(kohonen) #fitting SOMs
library(ggplot2) #plots
library(RColorBrewer) #colors, using predefined palettes

 
contrast <- c("#FA4925", "#22693E", "#D4D40F", "#2C4382", "#F0F0F0", "#3D3D3D") #my own, contrasting pairs
cols <- brewer.pal(10, "Paired")




#create and format data

a =rnorm(1000,10,10)
b = rnorm(1000,10,5)
c = rnorm(1000,5,5)
d = rnorm(1000,5,10)
e <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100 , replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25) )
f <- sample( LETTERS[1:5], 100 , replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2) )
g <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 100 , replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5) )

data = data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
data$e = as.factor(data$e)
data$f = as.factor(data$f)
data$g = as.factor(data$g)


cols <- 1:4
data[cols] <- scale(data[cols])

#som model
som <- supersom(data= as.list(data), grid = somgrid(10,10, "hexagonal"), 
                dist.fct = "euclidean", keep.data = TRUE)
```

From here, I was able to successfully make some of the basic plots:

```
    #plots

#pretty gradient colors

colour1 <- tricolor(som$grid)

colour4 <- tricolor(som$grid, phi = c(pi/8, 6, -pi/6), offset = 0.1)
    
plot(som, type="changes")
plot(som, type="count")
plot(som, type="quality", shape = "straight")
plot(som, type="dist.neighbours", palette.name=grey.colors, shape = "straight")
```

However, the problem arises when I try to make individual plots for each variable:

```
#error
var <- 1 #define the variable to plot
plot(som, type = "property", property = getCodes(som)[,var], main=colnames(getCodes(som))[var], palette.name=terrain.colors)


var <- 6 #define the variable to plot
plot(som, type = "property", property = getCodes(som)[,var], main=colnames(getCodes(som))[var], palette.name=terrain.colors)
```

This produces an error: `"Error: Incorrect Number of Dimensions"`

A similar error (`NAs by coercion`) is produced when attempting to cluster the SOM Network:

```
#cluster (error)

set.seed(33) #for reproducability
fit_kmeans <- kmeans(data, 3) #3 clusters are used, as indicated by the wss development.

cl_assignmentk <- fit_kmeans$cluster[data$unit.classif]
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(som, type="mapping", bg = rgb(colour4), shape = "straight", border = "grey",col=contrast)
add.cluster.boundaries(som, fit_kmeans$cluster, lwd = 3, lty = 2, col=contrast[4])
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Sources: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kohonen/versions/2.0.5/topics/supersom

Comment: This is a lot of code that’s irrelevant to the question. Please reduce the code to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem: generate a minimal dataset which, when plotted, causes the problem you’re seeing and post *just that* (via `dput`), plus the minimal code that causes the issue.

Comment: @konrad rudolph: thank you for your reply. I wanted to show a working example of the code, as well as the error - to give more context. I will only keep the relevant code. Thanks

Comment: @KonradRudolph : I have removed some of the irrelevant code, can you please let me know what you think? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getCodes()` produces a list and as such you have to treat it like one.

Calling `getCodes(som)` produces a list containing 7 items named a-g as such you should be selecting items from the list either using `$` or `[[]]`

e.g

```
plot(som, type = "property", property = getCodes(som)[[1]], main=names(getCodes(som))[1], palette.name=terrain.colors)
```

or

```
plot(som, type = "property", property = getCodes(som)$a, main="a", palette.name=terrain.colors)
```

or

```
plot(som, type = "property", property = getCodes(som)[["a"]], main="a", palette.name=terrain.colors)
```

if you must set the variable prior to calling the plot you can do so like:

```
var <- 1    
plot(som, type = "property", property = getCodes(som)[[var]], main=names(getCodes(som))[var], palette.name=terrain.colors)
```

Regarding `kmeans()`

`kmeans()` needs a matrix or an object that can be coerced into a matrix, you have factors (categorical data) which cannot be coerced into numeric, either drop the factors, or find another method.

drop the factors:

```
#cluster (error)  
set.seed(33) 
#for reproducability 

fit_kmeans <- kmeans(as.matrix(data[1:4]), 3)
#3 clusters are used, as indicated by the wss development. 

cl_assignmentk <- fit_kmeans$cluster[data$unit.classif] 
par(mfrow=c(1,1)) 
plot(som, type="mapping", bg = rgb(colour4), shape = "straight", border = "grey",col=contrast) 
add.cluster.boundaries(som, fit_kmeans$cluster, lwd = 3, lty = 2, col=contrast[4])
```

edit:
Alternatively you can specify the code directly from `getCodes()` by using idx like so:

```
plot(som, type = "property", property = getCodes(som, idx = 1), main="a"), palette.name=terrain.colors)
```

Comment: thank you @RyanJField for your reply! Just off the bat, a question I had: I doubt it makes a difference whether you choose to represent the SOM gird as circles vs hexagons, - is this correct?

Comment: plot(isom, type="changes") : do you know why this graph produces lines of several different colors instead of just one line? (as seen here: https://www.rpubs.com/loveb/som)

Comment: var <- 6    
plot(som, type = "property", property = getCodes(som)[[var]], main=names(getCodes(som))[var], palette.name=terrain.colors) ... the 6th variable is a factor, but the SOM plot displays a color gradient, do you know why this is?

Comment: plot(som, type = "property", property = getCodes(som, idx = 1), main="a"), palette.name=terrain.colors) : can you please explain this line of code?

Comment: colour1 <- tricolor(isom$grid)
plot(som, "mapping", bg = rgb(colour1)) ... a plot like this displays the data based on general similarity to one another (via the color) and also shows how populated each circle is? do you have any idea as to what these mean? plot(som, type="codes", codeRendering = "lines") ; plot(iris.som, type="codes", codeRendering = "lines")

Comment: I can not thank you enough for all your help!

Comment: Re: circles vs hexagons, you can change this by adding shape  = "straight" like so: ```plot(som, type = "property", property = getCodes(som)[[1]], main=names(getCodes(som))[1], palette.name=terrain.colors, shape = "straight")```

Comment: Re: plot(isom, type="changes") the iris dataset drops the factors and as a result only contains one code and one change, to accomplish this you would need to define som like so: ```som <- supersom(as.matrix(data[1:4]), grid = somgrid(10,10, "hexagonal"), 
                dist.fct = "euclidean", keep.data = TRUE)```

Comment: ```getCodes(som, idx = 1)``` should be the same as ```getCodes(som)[[1]]``` if using the code above (without factors) use this code from your original question: ```var <- ``` ```plot(som, type = "property", property = getCodes(som)[,var], main=colnames(getCodes(som))[var], palette.name=terrain.colors)```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227563/discussion-between-ryan-j-field-and-noob).